# Raspberry Pi to Esp32 USB communication

Tags: usb

I have a project which involves up to 9 esp32 connected to the raspberry pi 4 throught usb and usb hubs.

4 esp32 are "far away" (3.5 meters with a usb repeater cable of 5m length) connected to a hub, which itself comes to the rasp side.

The other 5 esp32 are closer (< 1 meter) to the rasp.

The hubs have their own electric supply (24V).

[image]

The issue: the setup of the serial communication is erratic (sometimes the communication works for all the esp, sometimes only some of the 9 esp32 are visible for the rasp), even if raspbian is always able to see all the ports.

This same architecture always works well if only 7 esp32 (4 on the left and 3 on the right).

I'm using Python serial library. The issue comes when I'm opening the port (at 115200 baudrate) which sometimes (often) results to `ErrNo 5 IO error` for a part of the ports.

If by luck the connexion is established correctly, all works fine after that.

So my question is: is it a known limitation and is there a way to bypass it?

Edit:

I suspect a USB limitation on the Raspberry Pi. Voltage or other...
Still in hope that someone here has some experience with that configuration...

Please use comments for any question, including what I could add to clarify my issue.

Comment: Please do not rant about other users or the site in your question.  If you do not like what someone has posted in a comment, flag it for moderator attention and/or ignore that person.  The reason your arduino tag was removed is because **this is not a question involving arduinos**.  There is hardly anything mean spirited in expecting your tags to be appropriate to your question.  If you are frustrated there is not a tag you would like to use and you do not have enough rep to create it, ask for it to be created on the local meta: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Some debugging thoughts...  Does it matter if you're powering on the RPi with the USB connected versus plugging in the USB when the RPi is running.  In either case "sudo dmesg" will show kernel messages, including any USB errors.  Of course, "lsusb -t" shows how the RPi OS configured the USB devices.

Comment: @ChadFarmer, I need to have the esp devices connected when/as soon as the rasp is booting. For other things you propose, I will try that and give a feedback here, asap. Thanks.

Comment: @ChadFarmer, in complement, do you think the limitation could be due to python? because "ls /dev/ttyUSB*" responds correctly.

Comment: @lemon  If lsusb and ls -l /dev/ttyS* show all of the expected (10) serial devices, then the user-level is suspect.  If lsusb or /dev/ttyS* do not show all devices, then the problem is below Python in uDev or the Linux kernel.  (I don't mean that uDev, kernel have a bug, just that more work is needed to figure out why things aren't reported.)

Comment: @lemon  I would normally write a small Python test script using the same imports and method calls as the production script(s), but just survey available devices and set baud rates.  And, of course, lots of status checking with debug output.

Comment: @lemon  Linux is just looking at USB connected UART (serial) devices.  Your Python library and scripts might be sensitive to the connection state.  Are these dumb RX/TX connections are they supposed to have control signals like DCD, RTS, CTS, etc.?

Comment: @ChadFarmer, thanks. ls /dev/ttyUSB* shows all the ports. The user is root (only root in this Rasp). On the esp side, uart_get_hw_flow_ctrl give 0 (no hw flow control). We've bought a mini PC as workaround (replacing the Rasp), with Debian: all works fine with the exact same Python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It may or may not be your problem, but I have seen an issue in the past with large numbers of serial ports and the device naming/enumeration process.  Specifically there appeared to be a race condition once the device number went above a single digit.  It was fine when I had /dev/ttyUSB0 - /dev/ttyUSB9 were fine, but if there was a /dev/ttyUSB10 things got exciting.  The symptom was that while the port existed under /dev, opens failed.

I never got to the bottom of the cause, but found that adding precise matches for each device in udev rules, and then giving each port a fixed name, made the issue go away.

Update:

I don't have a copy of the specific udev file for that system, but a similar one showing how to set aliases according to vendor ID, driver type, and serial number of the USB devices is attached:

Filename /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb-serial.rules

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial",DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio",ATTRS{port_number}=="0",SYMLINK+="modbus"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty",ATTRS{serial}=="01888D68",SYMLINK+="s2as"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty",ATTRS{serial}=="0001",SYMLINK+="apollo"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty",ATTRS{idVendor}=="03eb",ATTRS{idProduct}=="204b",SYMLINK+="cul868"
```

And this utility will extract all the serial numbers for use with your own rules file

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=$(ls /dev/serial/by-id/*)
UDEV=/tmp/$$.udev

if [ "${LIST}" != "" ] ; then
  for DEV in ${LIST} ; do
    udevadm info -a -n ${DEV} >${UDEV}
    SERIAL=$(grep '{serial}' ${UDEV} | head -n1)
    if [[ $SERIAL == *".usb"* ]] ; then
        SERIAL=""
    fi
    NAME=$(grep '{interface}' ${UDEV} | head -n1)
    VENDOR=$(grep '{idVendor}' ${UDEV} | head -n1)
    PRODUCT=$(grep '{idProduct}' ${UDEV} | head -n1)

    echo "For ${DEV}${NAME} add the followinG to a file in /etc/udev/rules.d file"
    echo "    SUBSYSTEM==\"tty\", ${VENDOR}, ${PRODUCT}, ${SERIAL}, SYMLINK+=\"meaningful_name\""
  done
fi
rm ${UDEV} 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks for this input, colintd. The bounty expires tomorrow... I've few time to be here on stack exchange (due to the issue linked to the question which takes me a lot of time everyday). Most likely, after several experiments and diagnostics, we have a electrical issue on the installation. This has been discovered today and corrected today (I hope). I can not confirm that absolutly for now. New tests tomorrow... I'll give a feedback here when possible.

Comment: colintd, we had no time to test your indication today. but since the bounty expires in few minutes and as you are the only one to post a answer (which may be good or not), I give you the bounty. At least, you tried to help (as ChadFarmer also did in comments). So, thanks. I'll give feedback here as soon as possible (and if I can confirm something).

Comment: additionnaly, could you add the way to change the udev rules in your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty.  Very generous given that you don't know if I've helped.

Comment: Additional information added.